# SQL - How to perform a calculation based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize for the poor title. I'm not sure what this would be called.

I have a table with the following data:

```
 Year     Item     Count
 2018     A        5
 2018     A        12
 2018     A        7
 2018     B        3
 2018     B        1
 2018     B        8
 2018     C        50
 2018     C        38
 2018     C        42
 2019     A        8
 2019     A        14
 2019     A        9
 2019     B        5
 2019     B        4
 2019     B        12
 2019     C        62
 2019     C        45
 2019     C        48
```

What I'm trying to do is get the sum of the count for each item by year, then do (A + B) / C for each year. I have a feeling that this should be simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

So the output would be

```
 2018 .2769
 2019 .3161
```

I got those manually by doing step by step calculations for (A + B) / C:

```
 2018 ((5 + 12 + 7) + (3 + 1 + 8)) / (50 + 38 + 42)
 2018 ((24) + (12)) / 130
 2018 36 / 130
 2018 .2769

 2019 ((8 + 14 + 9) + (5 + 4 + 12)) / (62 + 45 + 48)
 2019 ((31) + (21)) / (155)
 2019 52 / 155
 2019 .3355
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: One of the most important piece of information you can provide is which dbms you are using.  It's useless if someone give you a perfectly working solution, but you can't use it because it's in the wrong dbms.

Comment: Sorry .. I have SQL 2012 and use SSMS 11

Comment: @forpas thank you, i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  [Year],
  round(
    1.0 * 
    sum(case when [Item] in ('A', 'B') then [Count] else 0 end)/
    sum(case when [Item] = 'C' then [Count] else 0 end)
    , 4
  ) result
from tablename
group by [Year]
```

You can change:

```
sum(case when [Item] = 'C' then [Count] else 0 end)
```

to:

```
sum(case when [Item] = 'C' then [Count] end)
```

to avoid division by `0` if there is a case there are no rows with `[Item] = 'C'` for a year.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=64bb780f3e67ccfab418afa1c97b433c).
Results:

```
> Year | result        
> ---: | :-----
> 2018 | 0.2769
> 2019 | 0.3355
```